# how to trigger a function whenever the mouse on screen

Tags: javascript, typescript, animation, dom

I'm being stuck in a problem

I'm creating something like this: https://www.fariasviolins.com/

My English is not good :3
Specifically, I'm creating a infinity layout, the layout will be moved according to the mouse position(The larger the position, the greater the speed), it means that when the mouse to directions, the layout will be moved. I have tried mousemove and it worked, but I also want the layout still move whenever the mouse on screen(even when the mouse not moving, the the speed will calculate by the position of the mouse), I have tried mouseover, but it didn't work as I expected. please help me huhuhuhhu, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think mousemove is the right way to go!

On the example website you mentioned, it looks like the speed depends on the distance between your mouse and the center of the page.

If you calculate the speed that way, the speed shouldn't change if you don't move your mouse. (Because the distance between your mouse and the center of the page doesn't increase either.)

Comment: yes thank you sir, I have used mousemove, and it worked, but when the mouse doesn't move, the my code will be not trigger(the layout doesn't move), how do I solve it sir.

Comment: yeah, I'm calculating the speed in your way, my problem is, when the mouse doesn't move so there are no any events to trigger it (mouseover doesn't as I expect)

Comment: In the function that is triggered by the mousemove eventlistener, calculate the speed and set a global variable "speed" to that speed. Create another function, one that runs constantly, and move the page in that function using the value of the "speed" variable.